# My blender animation is blury when I try to splice frames into an animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I am new to blender so please try to give me any answer with this in mind.

Ok, I made animation with daz 3d. I rendered all the individual frames in daz 3d. I am using blender to "splice" the individual scenes together to turn it into an actual animation.

I made a "test animation" with an older version of blender. The test version came out fine and looked great.

I'm now using a newer version of Blender and made a new "test" scene. Everything looks fine before I hit the render button. I open the new rendered animation and see one of the characters is blurred and I guess pixelated when she moves. Not the entire character. Just the body parts that are moving the most. Interestingly enough they were NOT blurred in the blender window when I previewed the render.

I am guessing that the earlier version that came out fine differed in one of two ways. Either, the default settings are set up completely different from the earlier version of blender. Or the earlier test version differed in some way than this test version. The ways I see it differs is it is a completely different scene and animation and that the camera in daz was zoomed in a lot more in the new version of the test on blender than the older version test. The characters in the new test were moving quicker than the old test. And I rendered it in blender at a faster frame rate in the new version than the old.  But I am suspecting that with the new test, the body parts that are blurred are moving "quicker", I.E. move the furthest distance in the least amount of frames in the animation than in the old test. I say that because only the body parts that are moving the quickest are blurred. If that is the case, short of redoing the entire scene and re-rendering it, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi. This is quite a lot of text and I'm not sure how many people will read this amount. I have tried to reduce it a bit without losing the meaning by removing some of the 'chatty' parts, but if you can, try and simplify it further. I suspect some of this could be simpler if there were a few screenshots of renders instead of descriptions. Thanks.

Comment: getting ready for work and will try to edit it down tomorrow. thanks for advice. :) I hesitate to post screen shots as it is a bit "x" rated. LOL.

Comment: Cycles or Eevee? You can replace the character with any non x-rated one for your test scene...

Comment: Literally heading out the door for work now but I have never heard of either term before nor did I see a button to choose either. I rendered it on whatever setting blender is set to by default. But looking at youtube just now it looked like cycles. And I rendered it in daz 3d not on blender. When i say rendered I mean combining the individual frames into a animation on blender. You gotta remember I am a baby when it comes to this. Yes I will replace the character for a test when I have more time and post it here when I do so.

Comment: Ok, I upgraded blender to the newest version and I noticed the default setting was on Eevee. I changed that to cycles and made a VERY similar but slightly different scene and the blurr was gone. So I am guessing either upgrading to the latest version or changing it to cycles corrected the problem. Thanks everyone for your help. :) Just redid the blurry scene and it is fine now. Woot.